# Dart abstract optional parameters

Tags: dart

How can I abstract that a methods has optional parameters?

```dart
abstract class CopyWith<T>{
  T copyWith({}); // Error : Expected an identifier.
}
```

If I add an `identifier` like `{test}` it works and subclasses can have additional arguments

## What I want to achieve?

I have a complex state manager, I make some abstraction , the following code is a minimal code, show my problem

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

abstract class CopyWith<T> {
  T copyWith(OPTIONAL_NAMED_ARGUMENTS);
}

abstract class Manager<K, V extends CopyWith> {
  final _map = HashMap<K, V>();
  
  add(K key,V value){
    _map[key] = value;
  }

  void copyWith(K key,OPTIONAL_NAMED_ARGUMENTS) {
    assert(key != null);

    if (_map.containsKey(key)) {
      _map[key].copyWith(OPTIONAL_NAMED_ARGUMENTS);
    }
  }
}

class User implements CopyWith {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  User({this.id, this.name});

  User copyWith({int id, String name}) {
    return User(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      name: name ?? this.name,
    );
  }
}

class UserManager extends Manager<int, User> {}

void main() {
  final userManager = UserManager();
  userManager.add(1,User(1,'test'));
  userManager.copyWith(1,{test:'test2'})
}
```

Comment: Your base class takes no named parameters (and no parameters at all, really).  It can be just `T copyWith();`.

Comment: If I set as `copyWith()` , I have error in other codes, for instance `CopyWith c` is my parameter in a method, I want to call and pass arguments `c.copyWith(x:'y')`

Comment: @jamesdlin I added some codes

Comment: You can't pass parameters (optional or not) to a method or function that isn't declared to accept them.  That is, if `c` is declared to be of type `Foo`, you can't call `c.copyWith` with parameters that `Foo.copyWith` is not declared to accept. It doesn't matter if you have 0 parameters or 1 parameter of if they're optional or if they're named.  That's how static type checking works.

Comment: If you know `c` to be of a derived type, you must cast it to that type first.  You alternatively could disable static type checking: `(c as dynamic).copyWith(x: 'y')` and assume that whatever implementation of `c.copyWith` that's invoked takes a named  `x` parameter. (Of course, if it doesn't, it will throw an error.)

Comment: @jamesdlin , I updated the code , as here I have abstraction, I don't know how can I use copyWith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some one who has faced this issue in my library, I would say the only way is to not put a `copyWith` in your base class.

Why? Because you should only make a function polymorphic when there IS actually a shared calling convention and behavior. In your example, The way that these two classes perform `copyWith` is just different. It is, and should be, an error to send a `name` to `Manager.copyWith`, because `Manager` does not have a `name` to begin with. If you encounter a name inside a `Manager.copyWith`, that means there is some serious error in your code.

Also, if you actually try to invoke `copyWith`, as a responsible programmer, you will probably check if you are allowed to pass a `name`, which is,

```dart
if (someObj is User) {
  someObj.copyWith(key, name: name);
} else if (someObj is Manager) {
  throw IllegalStateError('You should not pass a name to a Manager! What am I supposed to do with the name now?');
}
```

There, you have already done type checking, so no need to make `copyWith` polymorphic.

---

However, some common behaviors can be made polymorphic, like `updateKey`. You can make `Keyable` as an interface, and `Keyable updateKey(Key key)` as an abstract method, and delegate to a non-polymorphic `copyWith` inside each subclasses.

Comment: can you show me an example please? my example here is so minimal, assume `copyWith` in abstraction class has many common logic, Must I copy past these logics in subclasses, somethings like `if (_map.containsKey(key))`

Comment: There are some nice Dart code generators that can generate `copyWith` along with other functions for your classes. `Dart Data Class` on VSCode for example. If you are REALLY not happy with this way, you can make `copyWith` take a `Map<String, Object>` as an argument and extract arguments by name. But `Object` will nullify any type safety and destroy performance, which is the cost of making `copyWith` shared.

Comment: Besides, a nice code generator can also generate `operator==`, `hashCode`, `toJson`, `toMap` for you, which are just crazy if you try to implement them in a base class. In my opinion, `copyWith` is the same as those method.

Comment: I'm not taking about just `copyWith`, I want to have a parent class keep all common logics and I don't want repeat theme in subclasses

Comment: Well in that case, you should break down those behaviors and only extract largest commonly shared behavior as utility methods in the base class. This is kind of in the domain of OOP design and can only be done on a case-by-case basis. But do not be too stressful about boilerplate, Dart and Flutter are never designed to be concise IMHO.